# Radio buttons for product attribute

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, radio-fields

Is it possible to have a product attribute and to have the input type as radio buttons?

Comment: In the backend?

Comment: Front-end  e.g. on configurable products

Comment: we might need more details, I am not understanding your issue. You can use template in frontend to customise your rendering.. so maybe you are after a specific attribute type and maybe you can't use a template..